# Get random phrases from an array in PHP?

Tags: php, random

I have this phrases ex: test 1, test 2, test 3, now how to show on load page in random mode?

ex function

```
function random()
{
    $array = ['test 1', 'test 2', 'test 3'];

    return $random_array;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put them in an array and use [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) to get a random key.

```
function random()
{
  $phrases = array(
    'random test 1',
    'random test 2',
    'random test 3'
  );

  return $phrases[array_rand($phrases)];
}
```

Comment: @Federal09 You're welcome :). Please accept the answer if this question is answered to your satisfaction (thanks).

Answer (score 3):

Put them in an array and pick a random element:

```
$array = array();
$array[] = 'test1';
$array[] = 'test2';
$array[] = 'test3';
$array[] = 'test4';

echo $array[ mt_rand( 0 , (count( $array ) -1) ) ];
```

Or you could just shuffle the array and pick the first element:

```
shuffle( $array );

echo $array[0];
```

OR, another method I've just discovered:

Use `array_rand();` See some of the other answers.

Comment: You have [`array_rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) for picking a random key.

Comment: Very good. In php 7 instead of `mt_rand` use newer and faster function called `random_int`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

function random(){
    $phrases = array(
        "test1",
        "test2",
        "test3",
        "test4"
        );

    return $phrases[mt_rand(0, count($phrases)-1)]; //subtract 1 from total count of phrases as first elements key is 0
}

echo random();
```

and a working example here - http://codepad.viper-7.com/scYVLX

*edit*
Use `array_rand()` as suggested by Arnold Daniels

Answer (score 1):

The best and shortest solution in php is this:

```
$array = [
    'Sentence 1',
    'Sentence 2',
    'Sentence 3',
    'Sentence 4',
];

echo $array[array_rand($array)];
```

**Update:** for above answers in as PHP 7.1 is to use `random_int` function instead of `mt_rand` since it's faster:

```
$array = [
    'Sentence 1',
    'Sentence 2',
    'Sentence 3',
    'Sentence 4',
];

echo $array[random_int(0, (count($array) - 1))];
```

> For more information about `mt_rand` v.s `random_int` see the link below:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/28760905/2891689

Answer (score -1):

Put them in an array and return a random value.

Comment: how to create array in php?? Sorry i'm developer of C#, php is very similar but i don't know